# Using Javascript objects to populate a menu, then using the menu to create DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI to create an interactive, 2D sandbox/canvas environment.  I have a list of pre-defined objects and attributes, and what I'm working on right now is essentially a "Insert Object" button.

What I want the process to be like is as follows:

1. The user clicks the "Insert Object"
2. A menu pops up, populated with my list of objects and their attributes
3. The user clicks on one of the object names, and a new draggable Div is created with all the attributes of that object

So, for example, if I had a list of objects like this:

```
var items = 
  {
   item1:["Oscar",
   "Grouchy",
   "Green"],
    item2:["Cookie Monster",
    "Hungry",
    "Blue"]}
```

I'd want the menu to populate like:

Oscar
Mood: Grouchy
Color: Green
Cookie Monster
Mood: Hungry
Color: Blue

And if they click on Cookie Monster, a draggable Div is created with some text labeling it as "Cookie Monster", a blue background, and some knowledge that it's hungry (i.e. if I later created some cookie objects, I'd be able to drag them on to it).

jQuery UI already handles the dragging and dropping bits.  And I've got some code that populates the menu from the list of objects.  However I'm not sure how I'd go about creating objects with properties based on the original list, and overall I feel like I'm not doing this the most efficient way.  What I have right now is as follows:

```
    $( "button" )
    .button()
    .click(function() {
        $.each( items, function( key, value ) {    //items is my list of items
            $( "#dialog" ).append("<a href='#' class='NodeCreator'>"+value[0]+"</a>"+"<p>"+value[1]+"<p>"+"<p>Input: "+value[2]+"<p>"+"<p>Output: "+value[3]+"<p>");    //#dialog is the class of my menu
        });

        $(".NodeCreator").click(function(){    //I made the name of each object a link with id NodeCreator
            $( "<div id='draggable3' class='draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle' style='position: relative;'><p>Drag me around</p></div>" ).appendTo( "body" );    //NodeCreator creates a draggable DIV, but right now they're all identical.  I want them to be dependent on which link they click
            $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
        });
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');                        
});
```

So how would I go about making each link create a Div that "knows" its own properties, and overall is there a better way to be structuring all this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think data attributes might be what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Yes, that looks exactly like what I'm looking for.  But how would I go about adding data attributes to the link?  Right now I'm doing $( "#dialog" ).append("<a href='#' class='NodeCreator'>... So how would I append it with a different data attribute for each link?

Comment: Think I may've solved it.  There's a jQuery .data() command that attaches data to elements.  So now I got it like `var test = $("<a href='#' class='NodeCreator'>"+value[0]+"</a>"+"<p>"+value[1]+"<p>"+"<p>Input: "+value[2]+"<p>"+"<p>Output: "+value[3]+"<p>");
    test.data("name",value[0]);
    $( "#dialog" ).append(test);`